# OpenCL clCreateFromGLTexture using a different texture target

Tags: android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, android-camera, opencl

The aim of my project is to get live camera feed from on an Android device, use OpenCL to perform real-time filtering on those images and render the output on display.

I aim to do this in real-time that's why I am using OpenCL-OpenGL interop.

I have successfully managed to create a shared context using EGLContext and EGLDisplay. Now I am trying to use clCreateFromGLTexture so I can access these images in OpenCL kernel. The problem however is android requires that when bind the texture the target must be GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES as it says here: (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html), however this texture target is not valid texture target when using clCreateFromGLTexture (https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateFromGLTexture2D.html).

So I am not sure how to go about this.

This is how I create a GL Texture in android:

```
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texture_id, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(texture_target, texture_target);
```

and this is how I am trying to create a cl memory object:

```
    glTexImage2D(texture_target, 0, GL_RGBA, 640, 480, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    cl_mem camera_image = clCreateFromGLTexture(m_context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, texture_target, 0, texture_id, &err);
```

The error I get when I try to create cl memory object from GL texture is CL_INVALID_VALUE.

I am pretty new to OpenGL so there could be something basic I might have over looked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The texture you receive from the camera is not the usual texture you'd expect. You even have to specify the extension in a shader if you read from it.

You need to perform an additional copy from the GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES target to another texture which is created in the usual way. With luck you can bind both of them into fbo's and then just issue blit. If that doesn't work you can always use the normal texture as a rendertarget and simply draw a quad textured with the camera image.

Comment: Hi sharpneli, thanks for your reply.
I have been reading OpenGL ES reference pages (http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/), but I can't find a way of binding GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES to a FBO.

Also could you please elaborate what you mean by using a normal texture as a rendertarget. Sorry I am really new to OpenGL and am trying to understand all these jargons.